# "View in File Explorer" is not opening in windows 10

Tags: sharepoint-online, windows10

I have windows 10 with latest updates and SharePoint online tenant. now I run this command to enable "View in File Explorer" for the document libraries:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Connect-SPOService -Url "https://****-admin.sharepoint.com" 
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-SPOTenant -ViewInFileExplorerEnabled $True
```

then  inside my machine, i set this inside the registry :-

[image: thumbnail image 1 of blog post titled]

I restarted my PC, then when i login to SharePoint, i got this option :-

[image: thumbnail image 2 of blog post titled]

but when i click on it nothing will happen. any advice?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Try using Microsoft edge browser.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP yes i am using Edge

Answer (score 0):

Please check this article for help:

[Troubleshoot "View in File Explorer" issues in SharePoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/troubleshoot-issues-using-open-with-explorer)